# undefined reference to a static constant variable collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++

Please help me

Error details as follows:

> src/a.cpp:2972: undefined reference to `B::XTT collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

`B::XTT` is a static constant variable in the `B` struct.

```
2969     if (index != B::XTT) {
2970         index_map_iter = lookup_index.find(merchandising_index);
2971         merchandising_index = index_map_iter != output_index.end() ? \
2972                index_map_iter->second : B::XTT;
```

It is very strange that the first time I use `B::XTT` on line 2969, it does not produce an error. But at 2972 I use `B::XTT`, and it produces an error.

And if I add `-O2` option when I use `g++` command, it does not produce an error.
But it does produce an error without `-O2`.

Comment: Is `B::XTT` defined? Not just initialized in the class definition, but actually defined?

Comment: Linkers usually don't list more than undefined symbol reference per file. Unlike when compiling, one error message is enough to tell you what's missing.

Comment: Thanks very much . I solved this problem with your help. thanks again.

Comment: Show the definition of the class B. At least the member XTT.

Comment: class foo {
    // omitted other members
    static int MyConst = 1;
};

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a static const member variable

```
class foo {
    // omitted other members
    static int MyConst;
};
```

you have to define it in one compilation unit.

```
int foo:MyConst = 42;
```